# Does anyone get the Tensorflow distributed training notebook to work?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

When I run this notebook, which is linked from Tensorflows documentation site,

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/r2.0rc/site/en/tutorials/distribute/training_loops.ipynb#scrollTo=7x7s5iYAYSGD

I get the following error:

> module 'tensorflow._api.v1.nn' has no attribute 'compute_average_loss'

If anyone can get it to work, what settings are you using in Google Colab? Python 3/2, GPU, Tensorflow version, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The github code is from may this year:

https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/commits/r2.0rc/site/en/tutorials/distribute/training_loops.ipynb

while the colab is loading tf 1.14:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

# Import TensorFlow
import tensorflow as tf

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import os

print(tf.__version__)

1.14.0
```

so your best bet is to run the program with tf 2.0.

hope it helps :)

Comment: Changing to TF 2.0 fixes the problem with missing 'compute_average_loss'-function, but then other parts of the code crash instead. The first crash is that the optimizer has a different initialization function in TF 2.0, which is easily fixed. But then the code crashes at the line:

train_iterator = train_ds.make_initializable_iterator()

with error:
'DistributedDataset' object has no attribute 'make_initializable_iterator'

That error is more difficult to fix because that functionality seems to have been removed in TF 2.0.

I would like to know which TF 1.x version it was written in

Comment: well, there are following version currently available: 

1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 

I recommend  you try the end of the list skipping the ones you have already tried